# Electric field between capacitor plates

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance, gauss-law

When we try to find the electric field between the capacitor plates, what is the right way to do it? This is one of the ways I've seen and I don't understand why:

[image]

Using a Gaussian cylinder on the positive metal plate, E inside is zero while E outside is $ \frac { \sigma}{ \epsilon_0}$

But from what I know about conductors is that the charge uniformly spreads itself out on the surface, not only on the bottom, so why do we take a cylinder that only takes into account the charge on the bottom and not on the top as well?

Comment: So the electric field due to one metal plate without taking into account the other metal plate, should be $E=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$ , correct?

Comment: @cazanova yes it is correct for a isolated metal plate

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have deleted my comment and have posted it as an answer as I think it pretty much answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implicitly taking care of the fact that you have charges on the other plate as well. You are doing it when you assume that $E$ is zero outside (i.e., below the bottom plate). Otherwise, you would have $E=\frac{\sigma}{2ϵ_0}$ both above the bottom plate and below the bottom plate.